# MySql prevent wrong enum query/stransaction

Tags: mysql, enums

If I have an enum of `gender ENUM('m', 'f')`

and the input is something like:

```
UPDATE person
SET gender = 'Z'
WHERE person_id = 1;
```

Result:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.06 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 1

+-----------+---------+--------+--------+------------+------------------+--------+-------+---------+-------------+
| person_id | fname   | lname  | gender | birth_date | street           | city   | state | country | postal_code |
+-----------+---------+--------+--------+------------+------------------+--------+-------+---------+-------------+
|         1 | William | Turner |        | 1972-05-27 | 1225 Tremont St. | Boston | MA    | USA     | 02138       |
+-----------+---------+--------+--------+------------+------------------+--------+-------+---------+-------------+
```

Warning is:

```
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                     |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'gender' at row 1 |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------+
```

How can I prevent the query from executing altogether if a wrong value is supplied?

Comment: sound like something you solve in a trigger. where you can raise an error.

Comment: Are you gender biased against people who self identify as Z?

Comment: Just tried other datatypes. I guess this is more of a question of how do you prevent execution when incorrect data is entered.